# Check if all values in array exist in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, joomla

I have some working code that currently generates a dynamic list of articles in Joomla. This is part of a quest system I am developing. Each article (quest) has a custom prerequisite value assigned to it. I've assigned these values using an extension called Fields Attach which allows you to define custom article attributes and store them in the database. The code below lists all quests with a prereq value of 0 or any quests with a prereq value that matches the article id of a quest in the completed quests table.

Right now, when a user submits a quest it stores the article information (id, title, etc) in the completed quests table. If a quest has a prereq value that matches the id of a quest that has not yet been completed, it will not be displayed. Hopefully that makes sense.

So, my question is this: How can I store an array of article id's? For instance, if I want a particular quest to have multiple prerequisites, I could assign something like 1, 2, 3 to that quest. But then how do I check to make sure that all values in the stored array exist in the completed quests table? It's imperative that I be able to assign multiple prerequisites to a quest to make this system work. It may help to show my current code:

This is the query I'm using to compile the list:

```
$query = "SELECT c.id, c.title, c.catid, r.user_id, r.prereqID, f.fieldsid, f.articleid, f.value FROM arp2i_fieldsattach_values AS f
LEFT JOIN arp2i_content AS c
ON f.articleid=c.id
AND f.fieldsid=5
AND f.value!=0
LEFT JOIN arp2i_completed_quests AS r
ON r.user_id = $userID
ORDER BY f.articleid, c.id"; // prepare query

$db = &JFactory::getDBO(); // get database object
$db->setQuery($query); // apply query
$prereqs = $db->loadObjectList(); // execute query, return result list
```

The php to display the list:

```
foreach ($prereqs as $prereq){ // loop through articles 

if ($prereq->fieldsid == 1) {
$questXp2 = $prereq->value;
}

else if ($prereq->fieldsid == 3) {
$hexValue2 = $prereq->value;
}

else if ($prereq->fieldsid == 4) {
$image2 = $prereq->value;
}

if ($prereq->catid == $catID
&& $prereq->prereqID == $prereq->value) {

 echo '<div class="questBlock" style="background-color:' . $hexValue2 . ';">' . '<a class="questLink" href="http://localhost/quest/index.php/quests/' . $prereq->articleid . '-' . $prereq->c.title . '">'  . '<img src="images/documents/' . $prereq->articleid . '/' . $image2 .  ' " />'  . $prereq->title . '<span class="xpFloat">' . $questXp2 . ' XP' . '</span>' . '</a>'  . '</div>' ;}

}
```

To clarify, let's say I have 4 quests with article id's 1, 2, 3, and 4. I want quest 4 to have a prerequisite value of 1, 2, 3. That way, quest 4 will not be displayed until quests 1, 2, and 3 have been completed. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all quests from the database and then filter these according to their prerequisites, you could change the `prereqID` field to `VARCHAR(512)` (or a different, appropriate size) and store the array of prerequisites as a JSON-encoded string. See PHP-function [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for that.

Depending on how many quests you have in your database, that might not be the best idea, but it's probably the easiest to implement.

Another possibility would be to remove the field `prereqID` from table `arp2i_completed_quests` and then create a new `n:m`-table `arp2i_prereqs` that maps quests to their prerequisites like this:

```
CREATE TABLE arp2i_prereqs ( article_id INT , prereq_id INT );
```

I used `INT` here, because I don't know the exact data type of your article ids. Change it accordingly.

For each prerequisite insert a record into that table that maps an article to its prerequisite. In your case that would look like:

```
article_id   prereq_id
----------------------
         4           1
         4           2
         4           3
```

When selecting quests from your db make sure to full outer join with this table or you'll filter out those quests that have no prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

As your quests stored in a database array, you could add a validation before you display the article and use php [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function for the comparison.

Here is the basic syntax example:

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Got mac";
}
?>
```

Good Luck!